# How to prevent system sleep with boost::thread

Tags: boost, sleep, boost-thread, standby

I see SetThreadExecutionState will prevent computer to sleep.

With boost::thread, how will I apply this to my software?
With disable_interruption?

Answer (score 1):

That's an operation system specific function, and completely unrelated to threading.

It's related to power management.

You could run /a/ background thread that does this in a loop, though:

```
void background_thread() {

     while (true) {
           boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(30));
           ::SetThreadExecutionState(...); // whatever you want to do
     }
}
```

Ironically, you would *want* to use interuption points in order to gracefully terminate that thread (although you can use whatever synchronization mechanism you prefer)